# DROP TABLE in Hive (via Spark) hangs

Tags: hive, pyspark

My attempt to drop a HIVE table hangs and is finally killed with the exception below. I thought it might a be lock, but when I try execute the `SHOW LOCKS` statement I get another exception (`java.sql.SQLException: Error while processing statement: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. show Locks LockManager not specified`). I event went to the Hive metastore and checked the HIVE_LOCKS table, but it's empty. What else might be the issue?

```
18/06/06 08:07:02 WARN RetryingMetaStoreClient: MetaStoreClient lost connection. Attempting to reconnect.
org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
```

Comment: _" checked the HIVE_LOCKS table"_ > Hive stores its read/write locks in ZooKeeper, not in the Metastore. That table is used for something else.

Comment: Did you try restarting the Metastore service? Because `SocketTimeoutException` is about a service not responding fast enough. Or maybe the table has so many partitions/files that removal takes too much time (HDFS + DB), and you simply should set a higher timeout in Spark's `hive-site.xml` (that option is not well documented though)

Comment: Hi @SamsonScharfrichter , thanks a lot for your hints. So there still can be locks on the table. Is there a way to see it in Zookeper?

The table is indeed large, but it is an external table, so it shouldn't delete partitions as far as I know.

Comment: `SHOW LOCKS` calls the "lock manager" that has been defined in start-up parameters. If none was set, then you get an error message like you've seen. If the default manager was set, then it will check in ZK. If a custom manager was set, ask the guy who wrote that custom manager.

Comment: Thanks @SamsonScharfrichter, that was indeed the case. Locking is disabled in our Hive and LockManager not set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the problem turned out indeed to be the timeout. The table in question had ~25k partitions and dropping took too long. I solved the problem, by first dropping all partitions in a loop and then dropping the table.

Comment: Thanks. A caveat that dropping partitions seems verrry slow. I have 56K partitions (I know I know -- came to this Q in the exercise of reformatting the table structure) & it's going to take hours to loop over them. I'm not sure if batching is any better

Comment: Confirming that batching is a decent amount faster but only roughly 2x so (deleting 10 partitions in serialy took about 3s, 10 as a batch took 1.5, and this scaled roughly linearly up through 200 at a time to about 30s)

Comment: Dropping partitions one by one is indeed extremely slow. In my case it took many hours per table. But it allows you to avoid the connection timeout.

Comment: I actually filed an issue with Hive about this, and it seems there should be some improvements in the bleeding-edge version of Hive (haven't been able to confirm): https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-22702